# Why is the function $T=\alpha(1)$ from ${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_n)$ to $U_n$ surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, proof-explanation, automorphism-group

In the [link](https://facstaff.cbu.edu/wschrein/media/M402%20Notes/M402L89.pdf) given, it is proven that $\operatorname{Aut}( \Bbb Z_n)$ is isomorphic with $U_n$.

I understood the proof until the last line where it says

> since, $T(\alpha) = \alpha(1) = r$, $T$ is onto.

Why is $T$ onto when $T(\alpha) = r$?

Comment: For any $r \in U(n)$, the proof shows that there is an $\alpha \in Aut(\mathbb Z_n)$ such that $T(\alpha) = r$. So the image of $T$ is the entire of $U(n)$. That's what it means for $T$ to be onto. Also, $T(\alpha ) = \alpha(1)$, but $\alpha(s) = sr \mod n$ so $\alpha(1) = r \mod n = r$.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Oh, Thanks! That was helpful.

Comment: Good to know it was helpful!